# Most efficient way to perform iterations over a list of dataframes in R?

Tags: r, iteration, purrr

I modified the iris data to recreate a simple version of my problem :

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

#Modify the dataset
data(iris)
iris$Sepal.Length.2019<-iris$Sepal.Length
iris$category<-ifelse(iris$Petal.Width<1.3,"small","big")

#Split the dataframe into multiple  dataframes based on Species
list<-split(iris,iris$Species)
start_year<-c(2020)
End_year<-c(2022)

#Function (Failed)
manipulate<-map(x){
 
   for(i in start_year:End_year){
    #Step 1:Create a new column with year suffix
    x[,paste("Sepal.Length",i,sep=".")]<-x[,paste("Sepal.Length",i-1,sep="."]*2
    
    #step 2 (The problem step):sort each dataframe based on value for a given year and category variable to create a cumsum of the sorted value
    x<- x %>% group_by(category) %>% arrange(x[,paste("Sepal.Length",i,sep=".")])
    %>% mutate(x[,paste("Sum.Sepal.Length",i,sep=".")]=cumsum( x[,paste("Sepal.Length",i,sep=".")]))
    
    #Step 3: perform more analysis with Sum.Sepal.Length
    x[,paste("Sum.Length.Compare",i,sep=".")]<-ifelse(x[,paste("Sum.Sepal.Length",i,sep=".")]>2,"Good","Bad")
      
      return(x)
  }
}

#Map this over list
new_list<-map(list,manipulate)
```

I get an error due to step 2 probably because I am mixing a lot of different elements. Is there any other package or formula that should be used here? The objective of the loop is to create new columns based on existing columns in an iterative manner.

I am really new to using purrr and apply family. Any help would be much appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Hi @ghq90. Can you please some example input data and what you expect the output to be? It's difficult to understand the format of your columns from your code.

Comment: Hi @ArtemSokolov, thank you for your comment. I added some examples. The expected output should have the new columns in each data frame in the list.

Answer (score 0):

This question hasn't been answered for 3 weeks.

I have tried to fix the issues of the `manipulate()` function using `dplyr`. Unfortunately, it seems that my knowledge of programming with `dplyr` and `rlang` seems to be too limited.

I must admit that I am more fluent with `data.table` syntax. Therefore, I tried to find an equivalent working solution using `data.table`:

```
manipulateDT <- function(x, beg_yr, end_yr) {
  setDT(x)
  for (i in seq(beg_yr, end_yr, 1)) {
    # define shortcuts
    pre_yr <- paste0("Sepal.Length.", i - 1L)
    cur_yr <- paste0("Sepal.Length.", i)
      #Step 1: Create a new column with year suffix
      x[, (cur_yr) := get(pre_yr) * 2]
      #step 2 (The problem step): sort each dataframe based on value for a given year and category variable to create a cumsum of the sorted value
      setorderv(x, cur_yr)
      x[, paste0("Sum.Sepal.Length.", i) := cumsum(get(cur_yr)), by = category]
      #Step 3: perform more analysis with Sum.Sepal.Length
      x[, paste0("Sum.Length.Compare.", i) := fifelse(get(cur_yr) > 2, "Good", "Bad")]
  }
  return(x)
}
```

The function is called

```
library(data.table)
new_listDT <- lapply(list, manipulateDT, start_year, End_year)
```

The result is too large to display in full length. So, to give an impression:

```
 str(new_listDT)
```

> ```
> List of 3
>  $ setosa    :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  50 obs. of  16 variables:
>   ..$ Sepal.Length           : num [1:50] 4.3 4.4 4.4 4.4 4.5 4.6 4.6 4.6 4.6 4.7 ...
>   ..$ Sepal.Width            : num [1:50] 3 2.9 3 3.2 2.3 3.1 3.4 3.6 3.2 3.2 ...
>   ..$ Petal.Length           : num [1:50] 1.1 1.4 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.5 1.4 1 1.4 1.3 ...
>   ..$ Petal.Width            : num [1:50] 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.2 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.2 ...
>   ..$ Species                : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>   ..$ Sepal.Length.2019      : num [1:50] 4.3 4.4 4.4 4.4 4.5 4.6 4.6 4.6 4.6 4.7 ...
>   ..$ category               : chr [1:50] "small" "small" "small" "small" ...
>   ..$ Sepal.Length.2020      : num [1:50] 8.6 8.8 8.8 8.8 9 9.2 9.2 9.2 9.2 9.4 ...
>   ..$ Sum.Sepal.Length.2020  : num [1:50] 8.6 17.4 26.2 35 44 53.2 62.4 71.6 80.8 90.2 ...
>   ..$ Sum.Length.Compare.2020: chr [1:50] "Good" "Good" "Good" "Good" ...
>   ..$ Sepal.Length.2021      : num [1:50] 17.2 17.6 17.6 17.6 18 18.4 18.4 18.4 18.4 18.8 ...
>   ..$ Sum.Sepal.Length.2021  : num [1:50] 17.2 34.8 52.4 70 88 ...
>   ..$ Sum.Length.Compare.2021: chr [1:50] "Good" "Good" "Good" "Good" ...
>   ..$ Sepal.Length.2022      : num [1:50] 34.4 35.2 35.2 35.2 36 36.8 36.8 36.8 36.8 37.6 ...
>   ..$ Sum.Sepal.Length.2022  : num [1:50] 34.4 69.6 104.8 140 176 ...
>   ..$ Sum.Length.Compare.2022: chr [1:50] "Good" "Good" "Good" "Good" ...
>   ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
>  $ versicolor:Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  50 obs. of  16 variables:
>   ..$ Sepal.Length           : num [1:50] 4.9 5 5 5.1 5.2 5.4 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 ...
>   ..$ Sepal.Width            : num [1:50] 2.4 2 2.3 2.5 2.7 3 2.3 2.4 2.4 2.5 ...
>   ..$ Petal.Length           : num [1:50] 3.3 3.5 3.3 3 3.9 4.5 4 3.8 3.7 4 ...
>   ..$ Petal.Width            : num [1:50] 1 1 1 1.1 1.4 1.5 1.3 1.1 1 1.3 ...
>   ..$ Species                : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
>   ..$ Sepal.Length.2019      : num [1:50] 4.9 5 5 5.1 5.2 5.4 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 ...
>   ..$ category               : chr [1:50] "small" "small" "small" "small" ...
>   ..$ Sepal.Length.2020      : num [1:50] 9.8 10 10 10.2 10.4 10.8 11 11 11 11 ...
>   ..$ Sum.Sepal.Length.2020  : num [1:50] 9.8 19.8 29.8 40 10.4 21.2 32.2 51 62 43.2 ...
>   ..$ Sum.Length.Compare.2020: chr [1:50] "Good" "Good" "Good" "Good" ...
>   ..$ Sepal.Length.2021      : num [1:50] 19.6 20 20 20.4 20.8 21.6 22 22 22 22 ...
>   ..$ Sum.Sepal.Length.2021  : num [1:50] 19.6 39.6 59.6 80 20.8 42.4 64.4 102 124 86.4 ...
>   ..$ Sum.Length.Compare.2021: chr [1:50] "Good" "Good" "Good" "Good" ...
>   ..$ Sepal.Length.2022      : num [1:50] 39.2 40 40 40.8 41.6 43.2 44 44 44 44 ...
>   ..$ Sum.Sepal.Length.2022  : num [1:50] 39.2 79.2 119.2 160 41.6 ...
>   ..$ Sum.Length.Compare.2022: chr [1:50] "Good" "Good" "Good" "Good" ...
>   ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
>  $ virginica :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  50 obs. of  16 variables:
>   ..$ Sepal.Length           : num [1:50] 4.9 5.6 5.7 5.8 5.8 5.8 5.9 6 6 6.1 ...
>   ..$ Sepal.Width            : num [1:50] 2.5 2.8 2.5 2.7 2.8 2.7 3 2.2 3 3 ...
>   ..$ Petal.Length           : num [1:50] 4.5 4.9 5 5.1 5.1 5.1 5.1 5 4.8 4.9 ...
>   ..$ Petal.Width            : num [1:50] 1.7 2 2 1.9 2.4 1.9 1.8 1.5 1.8 1.8 ...
>   ..$ Species                : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
>   ..$ Sepal.Length.2019      : num [1:50] 4.9 5.6 5.7 5.8 5.8 5.8 5.9 6 6 6.1 ...
>   ..$ category               : chr [1:50] "big" "big" "big" "big" ...
>   ..$ Sepal.Length.2020      : num [1:50] 9.8 11.2 11.4 11.6 11.6 11.6 11.8 12 12 12.2 ...
>   ..$ Sum.Sepal.Length.2020  : num [1:50] 9.8 21 32.4 44 55.6 ...
>   ..$ Sum.Length.Compare.2020: chr [1:50] "Good" "Good" "Good" "Good" ...
>   ..$ Sepal.Length.2021      : num [1:50] 19.6 22.4 22.8 23.2 23.2 23.2 23.6 24 24 24.4 ...
>   ..$ Sum.Sepal.Length.2021  : num [1:50] 19.6 42 64.8 88 111.2 ...
>   ..$ Sum.Length.Compare.2021: chr [1:50] "Good" "Good" "Good" "Good" ...
>   ..$ Sepal.Length.2022      : num [1:50] 39.2 44.8 45.6 46.4 46.4 46.4 47.2 48 48 48.8 ...
>   ..$ Sum.Sepal.Length.2022  : num [1:50] 39.2 84 129.6 176 222.4 ...
>   ..$ Sum.Length.Compare.2022: chr [1:50] "Good" "Good" "Good" "Good" ...
>   ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
> ```

#### Additional explanations

- The function `manipulateDT()` has two additional parameters `beg_yr` and `end_yr` because it is good programming practice to pass all relevant parameters to a function and not to rely on variables in the calling environment.
- In `data.table` syntax the line

  ```
  x[, (cur_yr) := get(pre_yr) * 2]
  ```

  alternatively can be written as

  ```
  set(x, , cur_yr, x[, ..pre_yr] * 2)
  ```

  or

  ```
  x[, (cur_yr) := lapply(.SD, `*`, 2), .SDcols = pre_yr]
  ```

#### Alternative approach

**TO BE COMPLETED LATER**